# Mac mail does not work after 10.8.5 update

Tags: macos, email

After installing Mountain Lion 10.8.5 update, mail does not associate to an email account and will not quit (Quit is grayed out - must force quit).  However, the email account is set up in preferences.  Library/mail/V2/maildata/accounts.plist lists the account and the Mailboxes are still present under Library/mail/V2/Mailboxes.  However, if I log out as iMac user and log in as another user, Mail works OK for a different email account associated to that user.  Does 10.8.5 limit the number of accounts for emails?  In Console, I get a MailIAPlugin message: "Tried to get settings for nonexistent account".  Any idea on how to get Mail to work?

Comment: This answer from the Apple discussion board worked for me: https://discussions.apple.com/message/20989931#20989931

Answer (score 1):

Grayed out Quit in Mail usually indicates that mail is busy doing something (like sync) and does not allow quitting.

Here are few steps you can do:

1- Run the Connection doctor

2- Enable the Activity window to see what is going on (get mail)

3- Delete that account and recreate it. (no worry, your email should be on the original server (ie gmail), but better check that before.

4- Wait for it to complete its duty. (like updating 10000 emails)